# iOS 10, Firebase, and PhoneGap - Getting SSL error

Tags: cordova, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using PhoneGap to develop a cross-platform app for both Android and iOS. Accessing `auth()` and authenticating users works correctly on both platforms, which I can verify in the Firebase console.

However, accessing the database only works in Android. When I run the same code in iOS, it gives me:

```
"Failed to load resource: An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made."
```

My CSP includes `firebaseio.com` and its subdomains, as does the `config.xml`. I can also verify that the ATS in Xcode is enabled, and it is generated properly when I go to run the PhoneGap app in the simulator.

By way of code example:

```
var adminRef = firebase.database().ref('/admin/');
    console.log('here');
    console.log(adminRef);
    adminRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
        //do stuff with the result...
}
```

Throws the SSL error. Even disabling APP Transport Security in the config (and thus the plist) doesn't allow the connection to go through.

Am I missing something? Everything is up to date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out. Accessing the Firebase Database in ios 10 requires you to disable forward secrecy.

In just the plist, this means:

```
    <key>firebaseio.com</key>
    <dict>
      <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
      <true/>
      <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
      <false/>
    </dict>
```

Or in Cordova/phonegap, you can disable it in config.xml:

```
<access origin="https://*.firebaseio.com" subdomains="true" requires-forward-secrecy="false"/>
```

In my case, I then began getting an error about a websocket call that wasn't in my CSP. It was, but it wasn't working. In my config.xml, I also had to add:

```
<access origin="wss://*.firebaseio.com" subdomains="true"/>
```

Now everything is okay in config.xml file and build works.
Hope this saves someone else a headache.